# How can I satisfy different string formatting scenarios with the same code?

Tags: python, python-3.x, string-formatting

I have an input file that contains string of placeholder text and associated values. I don't really know ahead of time which ones are coming though and was curious if there is a single code block that can satisfy all of the following combinations of placeholder strings and supplied values.

In essence I want this:

```
examples = [
    {"text": "There are {} bagels in a bakers dozen.", "values": 13},
    {"text": "My favorite bagels are {} and {}.", "values": ["cinnamon raisin", "maple"]},
    {"text": "I have not had a pop tart in 14 {}", "values": "years"}
]

for single_example in examples:
    print(single_example['text'].format(single_example['values']))
```

However `format(single_example['values'])` does not work for the second `text`. Instead I can do `format(*single_example['values'])` to allow the second example to work but it would break the first with the error `IndexError: tuple index out of range` and the third by slicing the string.

I think I need to make everything into a list so that `format(*single_example['values'])` will function across the board but I am stuck finding an approach that works for the above cases.

This works for me but I feel there might be a more streamlined approach.

```
for single_example in examples:
    if isinstance(single_example['values'], list):
        values = single_example['values']
    else:
        lst = []
        lst.append(str(single_example['values']))
        values = lst
    print(single_example['text'].format(*values))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can have an `if-else` inside `format` if your input cannot be changed:

```
examples = [
    {"text": "There are {} bagels in a bakers dozen.", "values": 13},
    {"text": "My favorite bagels are {} and {}.", "values": ["cinnamon raisin", "maple"]},
    {"text": "I have not had a pop tart in 14 {}", "values": "years"}
]

for single_example in examples:
    print(single_example['text'].format(*single_example['values'] if isinstance(single_example['values'], (list, tuple)) else [single_example['values']]))

# There are 13 bagels in a bakers dozen.
# My favorite bagels are cinnamon raisin and maple.
# I have not had a pop tart in 14 years
```

Answer (score 2):

You can store all values in a list:

```
examples = [
    {"text": "There are {} bagels in a bakers dozen.", "values": [13]},
    {"text": "My favorite bagels are {} and {}.", "values": ["cinnamon raisin", "maple"]},
    {"text": "I have not had a pop tart in 14 {}", "values": ["years"]}
]

for single_example in examples:
    print(single_example['text'].format(*single_example['values']))
```

**Output:**

```
There are 13 bagels in a bakers dozen.
My favorite bagels are cinnamon raisin and maple.
I have not had a pop tart in 14 years
```

---

**EDIT**

If you do not have control over the input data you can convert the values as needed:

```
examples = [
    {"text": "There are {} bagels in a bakers dozen.", "values": 13},
    {"text": "My favorite bagels are {} and {}.", "values": ["cinnamon raisin", "maple"]},
    {"text": "I have not had a pop tart in 14 {}", "values": "years"}
]

for single_example in examples:
    values = single_example['values'] if isinstance(single_example['values'], list) else [single_example['values']]
    print(single_example['text'].format(*values))
```

Comment: Yes. I suppose I could do that if I had better control over the source data. Thanks.

Comment: @Matt I updated my answer to work when you do not have control over the input data

Answer (score 2):

Why not using `try` `except` clause:

```
for single_example in examples:
    try:
        print(single_example['text'].format(single_example['values']))
    except:
        print(single_example['text'].format(*single_example['values']))
```

Output:

```
There are 13 bagels in a bakers dozen.
My favorite bagels are cinnamon raisin and maple.
I have not had a pop tart in 14 years
```

Answer (score 1):

Simplifying your existing code:

```
for single_example in examples:
    if isinstance(single_example['values'], list):
        values = single_example['values']
    else:
        values = [single_example['values']]
    print(single_example['text'].format(*values))
```

Output:

```
There are 13 bagels in a bakers dozen.
My favorite bagels are cinnamon raisin and maple.
I have not had a pop tart in 14 years
```

Answer (score 0):

Not much different from the other answers, but I would use two lists instead of a single dictionary and zip both the lists. Then for each index of the example list, unpack them accordingly.

```
def format_custom_text(string, values):
    # Unpack the values
    return string.format(*values)


values = [
    13,
    ['cinnamon raisin', 'maple'],
    'years'
]

# You don't need a dictionary to store the examples
examples = [
    "There are {} bagels in a bakers dozen.",
    "My favorite bagels are {} and {}.",
    "I have not had a pop tart in 14 {}."
]

for single_example in zip(examples, values):
    # Convert each value inside the values list into a list
    placeholder_values = []
    if not type(single_example[1]) == list:
        placeholder_values.append(single_example[1])
    else:
        placeholder_values = single_example[1]
```

Answer (score -1):

I think the following function is the best way is to check whether the value is “scalar” and branch on that. Numpy is a bit big to import just for this, but it works.

```
def as_iterable(x): 
    from numpy import isscalar 
    if isscalar(x):  # Includes numbers and strings
        yield x 
    else:            # Lists, tuples, etc
        yield from x
```

Now you can do this:

```
examples = [ 
    {"text": "There are {} bagels in a bakers dozen.", "values": 13}, 
    {"text": "My favorite bagels are {} and {}.", "values": ["cinnamon raisin", "maple"]},
    {"text": "I have not had a pop tart in 14 {}", "values": "years"} 
] 

for single_example in examples: 
    print(single_example['text'].format(*as_iterable(single_example['values'])))
```